# How to programatically detach editor in Eclipse Juno?

Tags: java, eclipse, editor, detach

In my RCP application, I am able to open an editor in Eclipse 4.2 (Juno), but I would like it to open in a separate window by default (that is, to be detached). I don't want to be forced to manually drag and drop it outside the main workbench window.

I wander around classes like IEditorPart, WorkbenchWindow, WorkbenchPage, IViewSite etc. but no luck so far.

Actually, it would be great to be able to embed editor into some dialog window from org.eclipse.jface.dialogs. But I don't think it's possible, as windows (as much as views) and Editors don't go well together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try looking [here](http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2012/07/13/so-you-used-internal-api/)

there is an example concerning views but I thik that it can be adapter to your needs

Comment: Thank you! It worked. The only thing I needed to do to adapt this code to editor's needs, was to replace occurences of "getSite()" to "myEditorPart.getSite()".

Usage of these internal classes result with warnings "Discouraged access: The type EModelService (and all these other classes) is not accessible due to restriction on required library org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench_0.10.3.v20120822-140642.jar" which possibly slows down the product launching and I must fix it somehow, but it works.

Comment: the warnings should be gone with 4.2